# Angular Pass Interpolated Data within an *ngFor back to component

Tags: angular, ngfor, string-interpolation

I am currently iterating over collection of Documents that belong to a parent (Policy).  I need to get a specific property from the element to send to my back end for processing.

When I use the bound data in my HTML elements things work fine:

```
    <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let el of policy.documents">

          <td>{{el.year}}</td>
          <td>
             <a href="{{ el.url }}" target="_blank">{{ el.docType }}</a>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
```

However when I try to pass one of the bound elements to a function (via button click) the data does not make it to my component.ts.

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let el of policy.documents">

    <td>{{el.year}}</td>
    <td>
       <a href="{{ el.url }}" target="_blank">{{ el.docType }}</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="button btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="min-width: 150px;" 
        (click)="getDocuments(el.url)">View Document</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

component.ts

```
getDocuments(url){
    this.policyService.getAuthorizedHeader(url).subscribe((res) => {
      this.authHeader = res.toString();
      window.open(this.authUrl, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes')
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error("Problem with your search: " + error.errors);
    });;
  }
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: have you added logging to the get documents function? any console errors? all looks fine at first glance.

Comment: In `getDocuments(url)` when you console.log the `url`, what do you see?

Comment: @bryan60 Currently it returns and undefined, but it (the el.url property) works fine in the href above.

Comment: @AliF50 Currently it returns and undefined, but it (the el.url property) works fine in the href above.

Comment: Try to recreate this issue in a stack blitz. It all looks fine

Comment: @bryan60 I dug back into the provider and found out they changed the property name of the object I was getting.  It was showing as undefined because it was looking for a non-existent property in the model.  Thanks for the look thought I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I found the the upstream provider changed the name of the property my model was storing (url to refUrl).  Once i updated my models to capture the re-named property it worked as expected.

Lesson:
Check the source of your data if things look right.